# Poisson Distribution Worded Problem (Typist & Corrections Question)

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

[image]

- The rate is 1/800
- The mean is 1/800*(200)

(a) 1 - poissCdf(1/800*200,0,1) = 0.026499

- 0.026499 = Probability that a page is deemed unsatisfactory OR Probability that a page needs to be retyped

(b) How do you attempt this ?

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability in (a) (I have not checked whether you are right), Then the answer to (b), assuming independence, is $p^2$.

Comment: why is this the case? Isnt it more than 2 attempts... not 2 attempts

Comment: More than $2$ attempts are needed if the first try had more than one correction **and** the second try had more than one correction.

Comment: Oh if it was 2 attempts it would P(more than one correction) + P(less than one correction)

Comment: I do not know what is intended in your previous comment. The probability that more than $2$ attempts (that is,$3$ or more) are needed is $p^2$.

Comment: OP means that if the number of attempts was exactly two, that would be $p(1-p)$. But it should be a product, not a sum.

Comment: Please do not use the tag (poisson-geometry) for questions related to Poisson distributions. The two are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to part (a) is indeed correct.  Call this probability $p_u$.

Then the answer to part (b) can be determined as follows.  More than two attempts are needed if and only if the first two attempts fail.  This happens with probability $p_u^2 = \Bigl(1-\frac{5e^{-1/4}}{4}\Bigr)^2 \doteq 0.00070220$.